# Pascal - bad number format

Tags: arrays, pascal

Program:

```
program s;
type 
  info = record
    name, surname: string;
    min, sek: integer;
  end;

  type arrays = array[1..50] of info;

var 
  c, b: text;
  A: arrays;
  gr_sk, grup_dal: integer;

begin
  assign(c, 'info.txt'); 
  reset(c);
  read(c, gr_sk);
  read(c, grup_dal);
  id := 1;

  read(c, A[id].name);
  read(c, A[id].sek);

  close(c);

end.
```

info.txt file:

```
3
4
yhgf
4
```

Please, tell me what is wrong with that. It says that it is bad number format for line 19 I guess.

If I change `min, sek: integer;` to `min, sek: string;` then it works. So as I understand, it reads number like string. How can it be? I have never experienced that before.

Comment: Donator, your `c` is text. That way you read only "string" data from the file.

Comment: You are wrong, that's not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i think

You are trying to read 'yhgf' into an integer (gr_sk), so when read reads, it throws an error because 'yhgf' can't be transformed into an integer.

What should you do?

Well, I think that you can read it into a string, validate that it is a number, and then transform it into an integer. Frankly, I don't remember the Pascal way to do it. After googling around, found [val procedure](http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/www.gnu-pascal.de/gpc/Val.html).

> Val converts the integer or real
>   number that is represented by the
>   characters in the string Source and
>   places it into x.

[Some tips on string functions  / procedures:](http://www.macdonald.egate.net/CompSci/Pascal/hstrings.html#str)

Answer (score 0):

I have many years to use *old* Pascal (nowadays I use Delphi), and I think you are using your `c` variable wrongly.  Anyway, in Pascal you can declare `file` variables and associate a record type on them.

Example:

```
  type info ...

  var f: file info; { <-- here }
  ...

  begin
     assign(f, 'info.txt');
     reset(f);
     id := 1;
     read(f, A[id]);
     close(f);
  { now A[1] should contain file data }
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
read(c, A[id].name);
```

to

```
readln(c, A[id].name);
```

Anyway I would search the problem in that direction; namely the not reading of the lineseparator. (CR and LF)

When in doubt, do a read(f,) and write the ORD() of a few of the read chars to screen